# Predicted values Machine Learning Python, how do I join them back to the set?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using Python for a machine learning model. I am trying to predict whether or not people will convert a membership. I Tried several models and now, one of them seems to be working well.

Next step: I want to make predicitions with my model. The problem I encounter is that I want to see which prediction is for which person. I tried to set the PersonID as the index. I use logistic regression in this case.

Problem is: I am not able to join the output I get from the logreg.predict method on PersonID. So I don't know what predicted value belongs to PersonID 1 and so on.

As you might conclude from my question, I am relatively new to the subject. So any help would be great! (preferably with example using personID). In demo's I see a lot of predictions based on manual input of for example 3 values, which is not helpful for my problem.

OK, my attempt to add code. Quite difficult, since I can not include actual data.

I have my Logistic Regression model. I fit the model and it works.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg_scores = cross_val_score(logreg, X2, y2, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print(logreg_scores)
[ 0.99561917  0.99679079  0.99617951  0.99567011  0.99709628  0.98298523
  0.99668857  0.99556778  0.9959244   0.99347904]

logreg_score = logreg_scores.mean()
print (logreg_score)

dataset2 = 
pd.read_csv('Predict.csv', 
index_col = 'PersonID')

Outcome = logreg.predict(dataset2)

csv file looks like this:
PersonID;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L
153;2;4;0;38;2;2;0;1;1;1;1;0
154;1;0;0;5;1;2;1;0;0;1;2;1
155;1;1;0;6;2;2;1;0;0;1;22;1
156;1;4;0;7;3;2;1;0;0;2;25;1
157;1;4;0;64;4;2;1;1;1;3;132;0
158;1;2;0;72;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;0
159;1;1;0;49;2;2;1;1;1;1;56;1
160;1;0;1;13;2;2;1;1;0;1;56;1
161;1;0;0;67;2;2;1;1;1;1;33;0
162;1;0;0;66;2;2;1;1;1;1;33;0
```

Comment: Please add to the question the code that you are using.

Comment: The output from `predict()` has the same order as the input. Can you relate PersonID to the input data `X`. Use same order.

Comment: @MiriamFarber: you get an idea now of what I am trying, but this is not code that you can run in your notebook. Is this suffucient to see where I go wrong?

Comment: Need the code from which you loaded the csv into `X2` and `y2`.

Comment: data = pd.read_csv ('...') X = data X2 = X.Values y = data['Conversion'] y2=y.values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predictions you get from `logreg.predict(dataset2)` is in the same order as the input. So the first row of the predictions will refer to the first `PersonID` in `dataset2`. Also you have directly used `Outcome = logreg.predict(dataset2)`. You haven't fitted any data yet, so you will get an error.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create some dummy data
X2 = np.asarray(np.random.normal(size=(1000,12)))
y2 = np.asarray(np.random.choice(2,size=(1000)))

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg_scores = cross_val_score(logreg, X2, y2, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')

# you need to fit the data using the fit function
logreg.fit(X2,y2)

# creating some sample data again
dataset2 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(np.random.normal(size=(1000,12))))
Outcome = logreg.predict(dataset2) # predict the outcome

dataset2.loc[:,'Outcome'] = Outcome # adding it to original data
```